# Is it possible to have an optional generic type for a trait?

Tags: generics, rust, option-type, traits

I need an optional generic type for a trait and I'm trying to figure out how to implement it in a nice way. Here's an example where I need it for a state struct:

```
impl<T> MyTrait<T> for MyStruct {
    type Value = MyState<T>;

    fn some_function(&self, state: &Self::Value) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Here's another example where I do not need it at all:

```
impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
    type Value = MyState;

    fn some_function(&self, state: &Self::Value) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

The generic type is only used to define a field type in the MyState struct. The MyState struct itself is always defined in a completely different way depending on the use case and does not need a generic type in all cases.

I know there exists PhantomData<T> for structs with optional generic types and I was wondering if there was something similar for traits. Unfortunately, I haven't found anything yet.

Could I maybe just add another type with PhantomData<T>? Like this:

```
impl<T> MyTrait<T> for MyStruct {
    type Value = MyState;
    type Phantom = PhantomData<T>;

    fn some_function(&self, state: &Self::Value) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Rust would probably complain about an unused type.

Lastly, I'm adding this to a huge code base where the Trait structure is already given and used in many places. I hope that I do not need to touch much of the code already existing.

Comment: How would `T` be used in this context?

Comment: The State struct contains a HashMap<Identifier, T>. The State is used in a Graph Analysis where each node has a State. T is used to store different kinds of information in the map. In some cases the State struct does not have this map since the Graph Analysis is completely different.

Comment: Might it be appropriate to add PhantomData<T> to all existing State implementations? This way T would not need to be optional. It seems to me like a dirty workaround.

Comment: Please incorporate that information into the question. If made into a proper [mre], the better.

Comment: Do you need `MyTrait` implemented for _every_ `T` when implementing it for `MyStruct`? If not, you could `impl MyTrait<()> for MyStruct { ... }`.

Comment: Have you tried just not doing anything? `impl<T> Foo<T> for MyStruct { type Value = () }` seems to work just fine: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a5e5c4fd69ef202adf8d25ae252d672e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need `MyTrait<T>` implemented for *every* kind of `T`, you can choose a dummy type to parameterize it for `MyStruct`:

```
impl MyTrait<()> for MyStruct {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: ...and where it's common, you could make that the default in the trait definition.

Comment: @eggyal Good general advice, but probably not applicable in the OP's situation, as "Trait structure is already given and used in many places".

Comment: But it’s not a breaking change?

Comment: @eggyal To me "Already given" sounds like the OP is not in a position to modify that part of the code, but that might be just my interpretation.